# find all descendant controls from given control without explicit recursion?

Tags: asp.net

Are there some static method which can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Control.Controls proeprty will return all child controls of the given control, but not the entire tree of child controls. 
But it's not hard to write a method that returns all child controls. If you are on .NET 3.5 you can use Linq to do it quite easily:

```
var allChildControls = control.Controls.OfType<Control>().SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<Control>());
```

Comment: As a side note. I needed to filter the Controls collection using OfType<Control>. I thought this wasn't necessary since the collection only returned Control objects. Does anybody know why this is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said without explicit recursion, however, I thought this answer was neat. Nothing special except for the use of the yield keyword.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/277654/645283