# Fetching control name inside html table in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Here is my sample code

for (int i = 0; i< sdtable1.rows.count ; i++) 
{

System.Web.UI.Control ctr = SDTable1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[i];

StudentDetailsChecklist.Items.Add(ctr.ID);

}

SDTable is my Html table, I want to fetch the control names not Id.

If I use the above code it fetches the ID of the controls, I need to fetch the name of the control.

Thanks
Rajeshkumar

Comment: You can do it easily using jquery

Comment: Please show us where you get stack rather than we try to guess.

Comment: I am just looking for the code friends.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar There are multiple ways to achieve it, but it all depends on how you create your html table. Please show us code how you create the html table.

Comment: Its a static table with static controls. I have to take the control name and pass it to the listbox. Its my scenario.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar: It always helps to see your markup.  That way we don't have to pepper you with questions such as: Does the table (and the controls) have `runat='server'`.  Is it inside of another control - like an `asp:panel`?  Is it created via ajax calls or through a web user control or is it directly on the aspx page?  etc.  In other words, show the code you have and someone will happily let you know what to do.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < SDTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Web.UI.Control ctr = SDTable1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[i];}. I like to fetch the name of the control stored in "ctr" instance.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to enumerating all the controls in the control hierarchy:

```
IEnumerable<Control> EnumerateControlsRecursive(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return child;
        foreach (Control descendant in EnumerateControlsRecursive(child))
            yield return descendant;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
    foreach (Control c in EnumerateControlsRecursive(Page))
    {
        if(c is TextBox)
        {
            // do something useful
        }
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277646/finding-all-controls-in-an-asp-net-panel)

Comment: I just want to get the names of the controls inside the html table.