# Finding all controls in aspx page by reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, ref

I need to change the visibility of many controls in my aspx page.

I found several methods to get the controls like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277654/1546137)

But I can't set values to this controls because they are passed by val, and I don't figure out how can I add the ref key word in this case.

Comment: `Control` is a reference type so a reference is passed. You should have no problem setting the visibility property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362482/c-sharp-get-all-web-controls-on-page), it should work fine. By the way, control is a reference type not a value type.

Answer (score 1):

From the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277654/1546137) in your question, do this:

```
IEnumerable<Control> EnumerateControlsRecursive(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return child;
        foreach (Control descendant in EnumerateControlsRecursive(child))
            yield return descendant;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (Control c in EnumerateControlsRecursive(Page))
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        var theTextBox = c as TextBox;
        theTextBox.Visible = false;
    }

    if(c is Label)
    {
        var theLabel = c as Label;
        theLabel.Visible = false;
    }

    ...
}
```