# How to Find all Dropdown Lists inside of UpdatePanel on Child Page of a Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, updatepanel, master-pages

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application that uses master pages and a single `UpdatePanel`. Inside this `UpdatePanel`, I have many other panels, which contain tables, which in turn, contain dropdown lists in the table cells.

I'd like to find all dropdown lists inside the panels and tables and check their `SelectedValue` for a validation method I'm working on. So far I have only been successful in finding the `UpdatePanel` and none of its child controls. I think I need to dig deeper into the respective sub-controls, but how to achieve this in a single method for all elements on the child page?

Master Page -> Child Page -> ContentPlaceHolder -> UpdatePanel -> Panel -> Table -> DropDownLists.SelectedValue

Have been trying many suggestions on SO, as well as Google, so far no dice. Any ideas?

In a nutshell, I'm looking to do something like this, but I think since my controls are nested in such a crazy way, the solution will end up being more complicated:

```
foreach(DropDownList ddl in d.Controls)
{
    if (ddl.SelectedValue == "0")
        HandleError(ddl.ID + " must have a value.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply @DMBeck.

I think I just found my answer, Good Ol' [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277646/finding-all-controls-in-an-asp-net-panel)

This code from that answer seems to get me where I need to be:

```
IEnumerable<Control> EnumerateControlsRecursive(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return child;
        foreach (Control descendant in EnumerateControlsRecursive(child))
            yield return descendant;
    }
}
```

And then...

```
foreach (Control c in EnumerateControlsRecursive(Page))
    {
        if (c is DropDownList)
        {

            ControlList.Add(c);
        }
    }
    foreach(DropDownList d in ControlList)
    {
        if(d.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            HandleError(d.ID + " must have a value.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you should be doing is client-side validation in conjunction with server-side validation in the on-click event in the code behind (assuming you are using older webform, not MVC).

For client-side validation I would suggest using JQuery Validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

On the server side just call the items by id, assuming the button is on the child page inside the update panel.